# How to install software development tools on OS X

Tags: macos, unix

I am very new to using a Unix environment. I have started development on MAC OS X. Where ever I go I see references to the /usr/local/ directory for installing software, but I don't see that folder by default on my Mac. Should I create this folder in order to do any development?

Comment: What kind of software do you want to install? Native OS X software goes to /Applications or ~/Applications

Comment: developer softwares like boost, ragel and stuff.

Comment: This question would fit better on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) since it's not really about programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OSX hides various parts of the system (including `/usr/local`) from the Finder. So you won't see this folder while in a Finder window, if that's what you mean when you say you can't see it.

You should look into using a package manager to install software, rather than trying to do it all yourself. Two popular options for OSX are [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) and [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org). Most likely before you use either of those, you will need to install [Xcode](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835) through the App Store and then install the Command Line Tools (go to Preferences and then Downloads in Xcode).

Comment: Thanks Homebrew did that for me

Answer (score 2):

Open up a terminal and "cd /usr/local". It should be there. The main idea of this directory is that you can install programs there and they will be "integrated" with the rest of the system, in the sense that the default command search path includes /usr/local/bin, the library path includes /usr/local/lib and so on. But you're by no means required to use this directory. Instead, while developing it might be better to use a subdirectory in your personal /home (or /Users) directory.

Comment: +1 for putting it in ~/local (but many tools need some coercing to install there).

Comment: ideafield-lm:~ dinesh$ cd /usr/local
-sh: cd: /usr/local: No such file or directory
ideafield-lm:~ dinesh$

Comment: That's the response I got. I am wondering if I have to create the local folder in /usr?

Comment: @DineshRtp You should *not* need to create the folder yourself. Most installers are smart enough to create parent directories if they don't already exist. Also, if you follow my instructions above, I believe that once you install the developer tools (Xcode etc.), `/usr/local` will be created.

Comment: i did install the Xcode already and like you had asked me, I also installed the command line tools and MacPorts. I still don't really see it.

Comment: Ok. MacPorts uses `/opt/local` instead of `/usr/local`. And again, you won't ever really "see" these directories visually.